# vBulletin OpenID Plugin

Tags: authentication, openid, plugins, vbulletin

Is there an OpenID Plugin for vBulletin? I need to be able to replace the current registration/login functionality with OpenID authentication.

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a fully production-ready one available. The best I know of is [this one](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=120923).

Comment: I am using this plugin too but I have taken some code for a link I just got from the net. http://goo.gl/0U8rB